# Java polymorphism method overrides

Tags: java, polymorphism

I am writing a program that has 3 specific classes, `ImageHandler`, `TiffHandler`, and `JPEGHandler`.

`JPEGHandler` and `TiffHandler` both extend `ImageHandler`. Inside of all 3 classes is a method called compress() which compresses whatever image the object is currently handling.

I am also trying to create a separate class that implements Runnable, but I don't want to have to create two Runnable classes, one for TiffHandler and one for JPEGHandler. I would rather just create a Runnable class that can accept a ImageHandler object.

My issue is that since the Runnable class only has an ImageHandler object, whenever I call compress() it throws errors during runtime saying that:

```
Uncompilable source code - compress() in fjimagecompressor.JPEGHandler cannot override compress() in fjimagecompressor.ImageHandler
  overridden method does not throw java.io.IOException
```

The second line confuses me, as inside of ImageHandler I have a blank method called compress():

```
    public void compress() throws IOException{    
        /*blank*/
    }
```

and inside of TiffHandler and JPEGHandler I also have compress() which throws IOException, except compress() does something different depending on if it is a JPEGHandler or a TiffHandler. I am unsure whether I am simply using polymorphism incorrectly or if I am missing something in my super class ImageHandler. Why is the compiler saying that the super method doesn't throw an IOException when I do indeed declare that it does?

Comment: You should post the code for your `*Handler` classes, but the problem is that the copy of `ImageHandler` that the runtime sees doesn't have the `throws` clause. Clean and recompile.

Comment: Wow...I cleaned and rebuilt and it worked. Thats all I had to do? Now I feel silly -.-. Thanks!

Comment: If you're not using an IDE, give one a try. Eclipse in particular can keep this sort of error from happening with its *incremental compilation* feature.

Comment: its wrong thing... why u just posting things withought any efforts?? its not the standard way... should first try all the things den you need to ask the question

Answer (score 2):

The issue is probably that your `.class` file and your `.java` file are out of sync, and while you can compile because you added the `throws` clause to `ImageHander.java`, you didn't get the compiled code updated. Clean and recompile your whole project and the error should go away.